# Why would the PS1 export won't carry on to a sub process?

Tags: bash

I changed PS1 value and then exported it but when I type bash to start a second process, PS1 doesn't appear changed there. How is this possible?

[image]

I ask since this sequence did work for me:

```
MESSAGE="Hi"
export MESSAGE
bash
echo $MESSAGE
```

Comment: Is `PS1` changed in your startup file(s)? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: Shell internal variables such as `PS1` should not be exported, as something set for `bash` is incompatible with `zsh`. In the interactive configuration, set the appropriate `PS1`.

Comment: Thank thrig. Siking, I don't know; It's a fresh WSL install and I personally didn't make such a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is exported, but the `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile` overwrite it without question. Run `bash --norc` instead of parameterless `bash`.